# Scriptable generation of 1000 PDF datasheets

Tags: pdf-generation, datasheet

I need to create over a thousand two-page PDF brochures/datasheets, based on data I have in a database. The layout will be identical for each PDF but the content different. What approach can I use to achieve this goal?

1. Design of attractive layout, including images/graphs. It should look like an actual brochure, not a printed web page.
2. Scriptable (any language) way to generate 1000+ versions with different data
3. Export of each to PDF
4. Maintainable, in case of future modifications/adjustments

Comment: You may be interested in http://go.applidok.com/en/howitworks.gz.html

Answer (score 0):

For this I took the approach of LaTeX + handlebars and scripting it together with node.js.

i.e.

1. Design example layout using TeX
2. Parameterise values using handlebars
3. Iterate through data set, replacing handlebars values with actual ones
4. Use `pdflatex` to generate PDF